# Is there any way to trigger onLongPress without user interaction?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

```
    GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: (){    
        print("LONG PRESS");
       },
    child:Text("......")),  

Now I want to trigger onLongPress without any user interaction.
```

Please give your valuable reply.

Comment: elaborate more with detail

Comment: Try to call actions from your `onLongPress` method by directly calling from any place.

Comment: @fartem 
Is there any way to call `onLongPress` directly ?

Answer (score 1):

**Here's how you can trigger any `Gesture` be it `onTap` , `onLongPress` or any other.**

```
 GestureDetector gestureDetector = GestureDetector(
    onLongPress: () {
      print('Long Press Called');
    },
    child: Text('Long Press'),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      gestureDetector.onLongPress();
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Gesture'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: gestureDetector,
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Output :**

```
I/flutter (19590): Long Press Called
```

In this code I'm calling `onLongPress` on `addPostFrameCallback`, which will be called after widgets are loaded. You can call `gestureDetector.onLongPress()` whenever you want to trigger `onLongPress` without user interaction.